# What is time complexity of my algorithm

Tags: summation, algorithms, asymptotics

I have this algorithm:

```
n=3;                          1
m=2;                          2
func(int n, int m)            3
{
    for(int i=1; i<=m; i++)   4
    {
        if(n>1)               5
        {
             func(n-1,m);     6
        }
    }   
}
```

How can I find the time complexity of this one? I know that for the for loop I can write:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{m}c$$

But I don't know how can I write the recursion in this loop.

Comment: How is `recLoop` defined?

Comment: @VHarisop I fixed it.

Comment: `func` seems to accept two arguments, but you only pass it one recursively

Comment: @DanUznanski Sorry copy-paste stuff. I think now it's correct!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The running time follows the recurrence

$$T(n,m)=mT(n-1,m)+mc$$ with $$T(1,m)=mc.$$

($c$ accounts for one execution of the loop and the if.)

Then applying the recurrence several times

$$T(1,m)=mc,\\T(2,m)=m^2c+mc,\\T(3,m)=m^3c+m^2c+mc,\\\cdots$$

and finally

$$T(n,m)=\frac{m^n-1}{m-1}mc$$ which is of order $O(m^n)$.

Comment: I would ask you to collaborate a bit your answer and also if you can to express it in summation?

Comment: What don't you understand, precisely ?

Comment: Two things: 1) Why $T(1,m) = cm$ ? and 2) If the solution is $cm^n$ than for $n=3$ and $m=3$ it is $T(3,3) = 27$, but If I add a ```count++``` before line ```6``` I'm getting 39 and not 27.

Comment: @J.Doe: I have refined the solution.

Comment: OK, what about the count variable I still don't get the right number i.e $T(3,3)$

Comment: @J.Doe: you do have the right number !

Comment: Yes, my mistake, sorry, typo!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73567/discussion-between-j-doe-and-yves-daoust).

Comment: @J.Doe: for me this case is closed. Enter another question if you need more.