# Time complexity and summation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, asymptotics

For the following algorithm:

```
n=3;                          1
m=2;                          2
func(int n, int m)            3
{
    for(int i=1; i<=m; i++)   4
    {
        if(n>1)               5
        {
             func(n-1,m);     6
        }
    }   
}
```

I have this solution [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2662211/what-is-time-complexity-of-my-algorithm):

$T(n,m)=mT(n-1,m)+mc$

But I don't understand steps to the final expression. Can someone describe a more detailed solution and also it is there any possibility to convert this expression to summation since it is easy for me to solve them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yves has shown you that 
$$T(1,m) = mc = mc\sum_{i=0}^0m^i$$ 
$$T(2,m) = m^2c+mc = mc(m+1) = mc\sum_{i=0}^1m^i$$ 
$$T(3,m) = m^3c + m^2c + mc = mc(m^2 + m + 1) = mc\sum_{i=0}^2m^i$$ 
From that, you can figure out that $$T(n,m) = mc\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}m^i$$ which you can prove by induction. After getting this form for $T(n,m)$, you realize that the sum is a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) and may be written:
$$T(n,m) = mc\frac{1-m^n}{1-m}$$

Comment: Can you please tell me in a more detailed way how you come up with summations?

Comment: @J.Doe I wrote $T(1,m),T(2,m),T(3,m)$ in a way that will make it easier to see the pattern. Does that help?

Comment: I want to know how you come up with the sum from $T(1,m) = mc = mc \sum_{i=0}^{0}m^i$

Comment: @J.Doe $$\sum_{i=0}^0 m^i = m^0 = 1$$

Comment: Thanks, I get it now!